# Badge number when push notifications? -- Livecode

Tags: push-notification, livecode

I have problem with badge number when send notification.

I tried lesson:http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/53405-how-do-i-use-push-notifications-with-ios

I'm working fine.When I send notification to my Application by livecode and open notification it.The badge number isn't lost.

Picture below:

[image]

And this my code:

```
on pushNotificationReceived tMessage
   answer "Push Notification Message:" && quote & tMessage & quote with "Okay"
end pushNotificationReceived

on pushNotificationRegistered tSignature
   --   answer "Registered for Push Notification:" && quote & tSignature & quote with "Okay"
end pushNotificationRegistered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out iphoneSetNotificationBadgeValue in the dictionary.  You can reset the badge on your app icon with;

```
iphoneSetNotificationBadgeValue 0
```

Comment: I tried this.It's working fine.Thank you so much.If when I send notification to device and User don't touch on notification and I send notification again it.How to set badge numbers increased?